# Issue with autoLayout and constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I have an issue with iOS and AutoLayout...it is a testing application where I have replicated the problem. It consists in a simple view controller, containing a fixed `UIButton`; when user clicks this button, the delegate have to create a custom view, apply it positioning constraints; the view has then a method to build his content views, and the child views are placed with constraints too.

Here is the code:

```
//MyViewController.m

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

  UIButton *start_but = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 40)];
  [start_but setTitle:@"Draw" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [start_but setTitleColor:[UIColor yellowColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [start_but addTarget:self action:@selector(clickAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

  [self.view addSubview:start_but];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)clickAction: (id)sender
{

  localView = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 300)];

  UIView *superview = (UIView*)localView;

  superview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

  [self.view addSubview:localView];

  NSLayoutConstraint *constr = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:localView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:100.0];

  [self.view addConstraint:constr];

  constr = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:localView
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                         multiplier:1.0
                                                           constant:-50.0];
  [self.view addConstraint:constr];



  [localView CreateGuiInterface];
}

@end


//MyView.m


@implementation MyView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self)
  {
    // Initialization code



  }
  return self;
}

-(void)CreateGuiInterface
{
  UIView *superview = self;

  self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

  UIButton *but1 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
  [but1 setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [but1 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  but1.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

  but1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

  [superview addSubview:but1];

  NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:but1
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:superview
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:-20.0];

  [superview addConstraint:constraint];

  constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:but1
                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                             toItem:superview
                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                         multiplier:1.0
                                           constant:50.0];

  [superview addConstraint:constraint];

  UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];

  label.text = @"Label";
  label.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
  label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

  [superview addSubview:label];

  constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label
                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                             toItem:but1
                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                         multiplier:1.0
                                           constant:-40.0];
  [superview addConstraint:constraint];

  constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label
                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                             toItem:but1
                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                         multiplier:1.0
                                           constant:20.0];

  [superview addConstraint:constraint];

} 

@end
```

So, the problem is that when i click iOS seems to have problem to draw the view background color. It is strange, 'cause if i don't use `superview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO` and put the view in a fixed place (with `initWithFrame:CGRect(100,200,300,400)` for example) without using constraints, it works fine: can there be problems using constraints in child and parent views? AppleDoc said that the constraints cannot pass throughout the view barrier; so i've written my app with local-view oriented constraints....
can somebody help me?

thanks in advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intent with autoLayout is to never have to setFrame on any of your views.  If you want to place your view programatically within your superview, you will provide constraints for that.  The changes I made you will see the background red as intended.  I didn't change your MyView implementation (simply added -(void)CreateGuiInterface;
within MyView.h).  The changes I made to demonstrate are within your MyViewController implementation.

Try the following code in place of your viewController:

```
@interface MyViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyView* localView;
@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIButton *start_but = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    start_but.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [start_but setTitle:@"Draw" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [start_but setTitleColor:[UIColor yellowColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [start_but addTarget:self action:@selector(clickAction:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:start_but];

    // The following constraints simply place the initial start button in the top left
    NSDictionary* views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(start_but);
    NSString* format = @"H:|-[start_but]";
    NSArray* constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:views];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];
    format = @"V:|-[start_but]";
    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format
                                                          options:0
                                                          metrics:nil
                                                            views:views];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];
}

- (void)clickAction: (id)sender
{
    self.localView = [[MyView alloc] init];

    UIView *superview = (UIView*)self.localView;

    superview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:self.localView];

    // Here I'm placing your parent view (MyView) 50 points on right of the superview with
    // a width of 400 points
    NSDictionary* views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(superview);
    NSString* format = @"H:[superview(==400)]-(50)-|";
    NSArray* constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:views];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];

    // Vertically 100 points from the top of the superview with a height of 300 points
    format = @"V:|-(100)-[superview(==300)]";
    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format
                                                          options:0
                                                          metrics:nil
                                                            views:views];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];

    [self.localView CreateGuiInterface];
}

@end
```

Comment: yes you're write, it works, thanks a lot. So, the problem was that i used to set the frame size with initWithFrame...setting the size of view as constraint solved my issue. thanks again!